# Was/were when listing individually

Tags: verbs, subjects, lists, agreement

I recently wrote something saying:

> Present at the meeting was the mayor, the chief of police, and city council members.

My coworker flagged this, as moving the clause to the end of the sentence would only make sense with "were":

> The mayor, police chief, and city council members were present at the meeting.

Though I am convinced that "was" does function correctly in my first example, every article I have found listing attendees uses the verb "were." Which is correct?

Comment: Why do you believe that "was" functions correctly in the first example? I don't see any good reason for that belief. (Perhaps you're relying on proximity?)

Comment: A, B and C were X. X were A, B and C. Very simple.

Answer (score 1):

Several people were present, making the subject plural, whether it is placed at the beginning of the sentence or at the end.

While spoken English may sometimes drop these rules, in written English subjects and verbs must generally agree in number.

At the beginning:

> The mayor, police chief, and city council members **were** present at the meeting.

At the end:

> Present at the meeting **were** the mayor, the chief of police, and city council members.

Have a look at the section on *Common Errors in Subject-Verb Agreement* at the link below: https://uwaterloo.ca/writing-and-communication-centre/resources-subject-verb-agreement